# What is the smallest positive common difference of a 6-term arithmetic progression consisting entirely of (positive) prime numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

What is the smallest positive common difference of a 6-term arithmetic progression consisting entirely of (positive) prime numbers?

are divisibility rules applicable here?

Comment: See this [Math Overflow question.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8664/smallest-k-term-ap-of-primes) In your case, divisibility tells us that the difference must be $\geq$ than $$2\cdot 3\cdot 5=30.$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, divisibility rules are important here.  Clearly the difference must be even as all primes (except $2$) are odd.  The difference must be a multiple of $3$ because otherwise two of the numbers in the progression will be multiples of $3$.  Carry on.  Since primes get less common as the numbers get larger, you should try starting small.